# What does $GL_n(R)$ look like?

Tags: lie-groups

Exactly as in the title - what does the general linear group "look like" (you are free to interpret this however you like) as submanifold of $R^{n^2}$? What should I imagine when I think of it?

(I am aware that the simplest nontrivial case is already beyond visualization...)

Comment: A related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/692862/homeomorphism-class-of-gl-n

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I will ignore the submanifold part of the question and just concentrate on the question of what the general linear group looks like intrinsically.

Via Gram-Schmidt, $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is homotopy equivalent to the orthogonal group $\text{O}(n)$. In fact an even stronger statement is true, although I don't recall the proof: $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is diffeomorphic to $\text{O}(n)$ times a Euclidean space, so really to understand its topology it suffices to understand the topology of $\text{O}(n)$. Furthermore, $\text{O}(n)$ always consists of two diffeomorphic connected components, namely the two cosets of $\text{SO}(n)$, so to understand its topology it suffices to understand the topology of $\text{SO}(n)$.

For $n = 2$ things are particularly straightforward: $\text{SO}(2)$ is just the circle $S^1$.

For $n = 3$ things are still not so bad: $\text{SO}(3)$ is just $\mathbb{RP}^3$, which is double covered by $\text{Spin}(3) \cong \text{SU}(2) \cong S^3$. One way to visualize $\mathbb{RP}^3$ is as the unit tangent bundle of $S^2$, so a point in $\mathbb{RP}^3$ can be thought of as a unit vector on the $2$-sphere: I discuss this [in this blog post](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2011/02/05/so3-and-su2/).

For $n = 4$ things are still not terribly bad: $\text{SO}(4)$ is double covered by $\text{Spin}(4) \cong \text{SU}(2) \times \text{SU}(2) \cong S^3 \times S^3$. $S^3$ itself can be visualized as $\mathbb{R}^3$ together with a point at infinity.

For $n \ge 5$ I only know how to make analogous statements up to [rational homotopy equivalence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_homotopy_theory). It's a general fact that any connected compact Lie group $G$ is rationally homotopy equivalent to a product of odd spheres; above those spheres were respectively $S^1, S^3$, and $S^3 \times S^3$. The general pattern depends on the parity of $n$ and I believe it goes like this: for $n = 2k$ even, $\text{SO}(n)$ is rationally homotopy equivalent to

$$\left( S^3 \times S^7 \times \dots \times S^{4k-5} \right) \times S^{2k-1}$$

and for $n = 2k+1$ odd, $\text{SO}(n)$ is rationally homotopy equivalent to

$$S^3 \times S^7 \times \dots \times S^{4k-1}.$$

In particular, $\text{SO}(5)$ is rationally homotopy equivalent to $S^3 \times S^7$ and $\text{SO}(6)$ is rationally homotopy equivalent to $\left( S^3 \times S^7 \right) \times S^5$.

For $n \ge 5$ it's also useful to know about the [fiber sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibration)

$$\text{SO}(n-1) \to \text{SO}(n) \to S^{n-1}$$

coming from the action of $\text{SO}(n)$ on $S^{n-1}$. In general you should think of a fiber sequence $F \to E \to B$ as exhibiting the total space $E$ as a "twisted product" of the fiber $F$ and the base space $B$, so inductively the fiber sequences above allow you to exhibit all of the $\text{SO}(n)$s as "iterated twisted products of spheres." Unfortunately you get different spheres this way than the above way since some of them will be even spheres.

The fiber sequences above also tell you that for fixed $i$, the homotopy groups $\pi_i(\text{SO}(n))$ stabilize as $n \to \infty$. The stable values are the homotopy groups of the [stable (special) orthogonal group](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/stable+orthogonal+group) $\text{SO}$ and they are the subject of (real) [Bott periodicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bott_periodicity_theorem).

Comment: The diffeomorphism you mention can be obtained, for example, from Gram-Schmidt, as you said, getting $A=QR$, with $Q$ orthogonal and $R$ upper triangular with positive diagonal entries. It's not hard to prove that the set of such $R$ is diffeo to $\Bbb R^{n(n+1)/2}$.

Answer (score 9):

It's a big open subset. The set of singular matrices forms a conical hypersurface (with cone point at the origin).

You can see this quite explicitly for $GL(2)$, which is the complement of the hypersurface $x_1x_4-x_2x_3=0$ in $\Bbb R^4$.

Comment: Thanks. So the fact that the complement is in general a conical hypersurface follows from the determinant being a homogenous polynomial of degree n?

Comment: Yes, absitively.

Comment: What can one do to understand the geometry of $SL_n(R)$? Its complement is no longer a variety, at least in a way that is obvious to me.

Comment: No, it itself is a closed submanifold of codimension 1. Not that this helps, but $GL(n)$ is diffeomorphic to $SL(n)\times (\Bbb R-\{0\})$. Why?

Comment: Presumably because a matrix in $GL(n)$ can be decomposed as $\lambda B$, where $\lambda$ is its determinant and $B \in SL(n)$? The determinant (representing the coset of $GL(n) / SL(n)$) and the representative in $SL(n)$ are well defined and smooth projection maps. (The later is smooth because the determinant is smooth and nonzero, so we can invert it to get the matrix $\lambda^{-1} I$. And since $GL(n)$ is a Lie group, multiplication by this matrix is smooth.) I think. So now one could argue that $GL(n)$ (with these projections) satisfies the universal property for products.

Comment: @user: if $\lambda$ means the diagonal matrix with diagonal values $\lambda$, then this is not true. You need to pick a splitting of the exact sequence $\text{SL}_n \to \text{GL}_n \to \text{GL}_1$ and there are many such splittings.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks. You're right - I don't think that I can just naively take the nth root either. I'll work this out as an exercise then. That would probably be good for me.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Oh - no, you're completely right. You just choose one splitting. Of which there are many. For example, fixing a positive branch of the nth root of the absolute value, and using some fixed diagonal entry to account for sign.

Comment: For a diffeomorphism that has no interplay with the group structure, you can pull a scalar into one column only of the matrix.