# Topology of orthogonal groups when $n > 4$?

Tags: lie-groups

[On Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group#Low-dimensional_topology) I read that the topologies of $O(1)$ and $SO(1)$ to $SO(4)$ are known topological spaces.

What about $O(n), SO(n), U(n)$ when $n>4$?

Comment: Well, that depends on what you mean by "known." I more or less answer this question for the orthogonal groups here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/902552/what-does-gl-nr-look-like

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I'll have to study your answer but a brief glimpse suggests it's what I'm asking.