# The homotopy type of the space of symplectic structures

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, lie-groups, homotopy-theory, fibration

While reading the book *Introduction to the $h$-Principle* by Y. Eliashberg and N. Mishachev, I noticed that the authors state, at the end of section 9.1.A, that the space of all symplectic structures on Euclidean space $\mathbb R^{2n}$, which they identify as $\text{GL}(2n,\mathbb R)/\text{Sp}(2n)$, ***is not contractible***, whereas the space of all Euclidean structures of the aforementioned space, which can be identified with $\text{GL}(2n,\mathbb R)/\text{O}(2n)$, ***is contractible***.

How can one prove such assertions? I am not familiar with homotopy theory at all, so I am totally clueless on how to proceed.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

**Edit:** as the comments suggest, it is easy to prove that the space of symplectic structures is not contractible. However, in the book, it is asserted that this space has exactly two connected components, and that both are not contractible. So, how can we prove these statements?

Comment: An easy thing that one can say is that $GL(2n,\mathbb{R})/Sp(2n)$ is not connected, since the determinant of a symplectic matrix is always $1$, so there is a (non-constant) continuous map $GL(2n,\mathbb{R})/Sp(2n)\to \{\pm 1\}$ sending the class of $[A]$ to the sign of $\det(A)$. (On the other hand that does not work with  $GL(2n,\mathbb{R})/O(2n)$ since orthogonal matrices can have determinant $-1$). So you can easily see that $GL(2n,\mathbb{R})/Sp(2n)$ is not contractible.

Comment: The first quotient is not even connected. For the second quotient, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/692862/homeomorphism-class-of-gl-n).

Comment: $GL(2n,R)/Sp(n)\sim SO(n)/SU(n)$ and the latter is a closed manifold of positive dimension, hence, not contractible (just look at the top homology group).